# Inland / crater watershed delination

Tags: qgis, arcgis-10.0, hydrology, watershed

Even though watershed delineation is a quite popular matter here, I have what seems to be a somewhat unusual demand.

I start with a DEM which is constituted of a series of craters, all centered on one point which is the lowest part of the crater.

[Here is a picture of my DEM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtHBV.png)

What I want to to, is to obtain the drainage basin of each crater.

I know how to delineate watersheds using ArcGIS' Hydrology tools, but they are best suited for 'open' hydrological systems (flows try to reach the exterior of the raster).

[Here is the result I obtain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bc1O3.png). How comes some of my drainage basins are obviously wrong? Why is Arcgis so lazy that its scope is limited to the rectangle limited by the four most extreme (N-S-W-E) points?

Therefore, my question is the following: is it possible to automatically delineate the watershed basin and set the center of my craters as the targets where my flows should go?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Damien

[Edit : added Arcgis output for clarity]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default for the watershed tool is to limit the output extent to the same as your input pour points. You can change this in the [Output Extent (Environment setting)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Output_Extent/001w00000009000000/) to the maximum of inputs or same as the original DEM. For more info see [The analysis environment of Spatial Analyst](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/The_analysis_environment_of_Spatial_Analyst/005900000019000000/). Try the [Snap Pour Point](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Snap_Pour_Point/009z00000055000000/) tool to see if this helps ensure that your crater centers are at the cell of highest flow accumulation (i.e. lowest spot in each crater).

Comment: Thanks for your help! [Here is the result](http://i.imgur.com/zYYBZYZ.png) I obtained following your tips. Snapping the pour points really did the difference. I still have one empty part, but I think this one is only a question of resolution. Thanks again!